# How to get access to XNA reference in windows form application

Tags: winforms, xna

I am trying to get access to the Vector2 objects in a form application, but when I add the refence to XNA.Framework it says that it cannot be found. (But clearly the file exists) Any way to mitigate around this?

Comment: No problem trying this.  VS2010 and targeting .NET 4.0 is required.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?  And what version of XNA are you trying to reference?

Comment: XNA 3.1, using Visual Studio 2008.

Comment: Is the app in AnyCPU or x64? If I recall right, XNA only has 32-bit binaries. (Ref: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2008/02/25/xna-framework-on-64-bit-windows.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had my build in AnyCPU, thus it was building in x64 natively. I simply right clicked the solution in Solution Explorer, went to Configuration Manager, and created a new build platform. (x86) Builds. :)